# How to prove that if $x>0$ and $y>0$, then $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}>\sqrt{x+y}$, using the relation of arithmetic and geometric means?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, triangle-inequality

> How to prove that if $x>0$ and $y>0$, then $$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}>\sqrt{x+y}\,,$$ using the relation of arithmetic and geometric means?

I started by showing that if $x>0$ and $y>0$, based on the relation of arithmetic and geometric means, $\dfrac{x+y}{2}\ge\sqrt{xy}$.

Hence, $x+y\ge2\sqrt{xy}$.

I am now stuck here and don't know what must be the next step.

Any suggestions or comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to proofs that don't use AM-GM? @DrZafarAhmedDSc's answer presents an alternative.

Comment: Thank you but I would like to know how I can use the relationship of AM-GM to prove this. I was able to prove this without the use of said relationship. My professor says that we can use AM-GM.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for $x,y \gt 0$, we have$\sqrt{x+y}=\sqrt {\sqrt{x}^2+\sqrt y^2}\lt \sqrt{\sqrt x^2+\sqrt y^2+2\sqrt x\sqrt y}=\sqrt{(\sqrt x+\sqrt y) ^2} =\sqrt x+ \sqrt y$

Answer (score 4):

If $x,y>0$, then squaring the following on both sides
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}>\sqrt{x+y} $$
we have, $$x+y+2\sqrt{xy} > x+y \implies 2\sqrt{xy} >0,$$
which is true.

Comment: It would be better to write these implications as if and only ifs (which is just as easily true). Showing that $P$ implies a true statement does not prove that it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Is this correct?

Since $x+y≥2\sqrt{xy}$, by AM-GM relationship,

$x+y+2\sqrt{xy}≥x+y$

$(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2≥x+y$

Thus, $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}>\sqrt{x+y}$. QED.

Comment: While the inequality $x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\geq x+y$ is true, I don't see how you concluded from the AM-GM Inequality you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem (A Baby Version of the Triangle Inequality).**    Let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ be real numbers.  We have
> $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\geq \sqrt{(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2}\,.$$
> The equality holds if and only if
>
> - $(a,b)=(0,0)$, or
> - there exists $\lambda\geq 0$ such that $(c,d)=(\lambda a,\lambda b)$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be nonnegative real numbers.  Note that
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}^2+0^2}+\sqrt{0^2+\sqrt{y}^2}\,.$$
By the Baby Triangle Inequality above,
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x}^2+0^2}+\sqrt{0^2+\sqrt{y}^2}\geq \sqrt{(\sqrt{x}+0)^2+(0+\sqrt{y})^2}\,.$$
That is,
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\geq \sqrt{x+y}\,.\tag{#}$$
By the equality conditions of the Baby Triangle Inequality, (#) is an equality if and only if $x=0$ or $y=0$.

> Now, I shall prove the Baby Triangle Inequality using the AM-GM Inequality to fulfill the OP's request that the AM-GM Inequality must be used.  By squaring the required inequality, what we need to prove is equivalent to
> $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\geq ac+bd\,.$$
> We, in fact, have a stronger inequality:
> $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\geq |a|\,|c|+|b|\,|d|\,. \tag{*}$$
> By squaring the inequality above, we know that (*) is equivalent to
> $$a^2d^2+b^2c^2\geq 2\,|a|\,|b|\,|c|\,|d|\,,$$ which is true by the AM-GM Inequality:
> $$\frac{a^2d^2+b^2c^2}{2}=\frac{|ad|^2+|bc|^2}{2}\geq \sqrt{|ad|^2\cdot |bc|^2}=|a|\,|b|\,|c|\,|d|\,.$$